# c# EF Model has foreign key to another model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the following two models:

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Type {get; set;}
  ..other properties
}

public class Person
{
  public int PersonId {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int CategoryId {get; set;}
  [ForeignKey["CategoryId"])
  public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

I have a repository class that carries out something like the following to get all Person thats have a category of a particular type:

```
var result = repo.FindBy<Person>(p=>p.Category.Type == 1).ToList()
```

My repository method as requested by Ivan:

```
 public IQueryable<T> FindBy<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) where T : class
    {

            return _context.Set<T>().Where(filter).AsQueryable();
    }
```

I get an "Object Not set to" error on the .Type property because I believe it is not linking the two models. I believe this is because the foreign keys do not match (is it using Reflection?). 
I am not able to rename Category.Id to Category.CategoryId in the database. 
Is there anything i can do on either models to be able to link the Category whenever I select from the Person table by setting a data annotation on either property?

Comment: There is something wrong with your `Find` method. Most likely you are passing `Func<...>` while you should really passing `Expression<Func<..>>` so the criteria is translated to SQL. Or you have lazy loading disabled. Or the method should have `Include` statement. Etc. W/o seeing the `Find` method, there is nothing we can help.

Comment: @IvanStoev Find belongs to EF :))) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @Adrian do you have to use find? i'd try `var result = repo.Persons.Include(p => p.Category).Where(p=>p.Category.Type == 1).ToList()`

Comment: Ive updated my question with the repo as requested. I don't believe it is a lazy load problem but more that my property is called CategoryId which doesn't match anything in the Category table/model?

Comment: Well, with the posted `FindBy` method implementation, there is absolutely no way to get NRE exception. Except if you are using EF Core, do you?

Comment: if I do a repo.FindBy<Person>().First().Category.....then the answer is null

Comment: That's another story. We are discussing the code you posted. But anyway, did you try adding `.Include(p => p.Category)` before `.Where(...)` ? Btw, your model is just fine, the name of the PK column in `Category` table really doesn't matter.